# react-select V2 - how to achieve `overflow-x: hidden` on an `isMulti` `ValueContainer`

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to figure out how to get a [react-select V2](https://react-select.com/home) component which is set to `isMulti` to hide the selected values once they exceed the `ValueContainer`'s width (instead of breaking to a new line and expanding the component's height).

I tried achieving this (with no luck) by applying the following style to the `valueContainer`:

```
 valueContainer: base => ({
            ...base,
            overflowX: "hidden"
          })
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vy93jrm6l) of the **unwanted** behavior (my goal is to get the 3rd value to be partially hidden or truncated on the same line as the other 2 values instead of appearing on a new line).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the css style [`inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).

```
valueContainer: base => ({
        ...base,
        display: "inline-block",
        overflowX: "hidden"
      })
```

If you also apply this style to the `input` element, it will avoid wrapping as well.

```
    valueContainer: base => ({
        ...base,
        display: "inline-block",
        overflowX: "hidden"
      }),
    input: base => ({
        ...base,
        display: "inline-block"
      })
```

And, if you prevent breaking between blocks, by adding `whiteSpace: 'nowrap'` to the containing `control`, that should keep all the elements on the same line:

```
      control: base => ({
        ...base,
        width: 200,
        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
      }),
      menu: base => ({ ...base, width: 200 }),
      valueContainer: base => ({
        ...base,
        overflowX: "hidden",
        display: "inline-block"
      }),
      input: base => ({
        ...base,
        display: "inline-block"
      })
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed does the trick of hiding the overflowing values. However, it doesn't completely solve the issue with the expanding height, since once values are inserted to the container, the `Input` component breaks down to a new line. I tried styling it as `inline-block` as well - or even setting `isSearchable` to `false` on the main `Select` component, but the extra row at the bottom of the field is still created as soon as the width limit on the top row is reached. Any ideas how I can deal with this (ideally with keeping the component searchable)?

Comment: @itaydafna you can apply a similar style `inline-block` to the `input` element so that it also doesn't wrap.  I have updated my answer to include this additional tip.

Comment: I see what you are saying and I also tried this solution - however, for some reason (probably because how the `Input` component is wrapped) it keeps on breaking to a new line as soon as the width of the first line is exceeded.

Comment: @itaydafna please see the latest edit to my answer, if you apply `whiteSpace: 'nowrap'` to the containing `control` then I believe you will see the styling you want.